# How to prevent app from re-sorting data using reselector

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am using reselector to prevent my app from recalculating data. 
In my case. I have nested `redux` state like this:

```
state: {
    data: [
        data1:[1, 2, 3],
        data2: [7, 8, 9, 10],
        ...
        dataN: [4, 5, 6]
    ]
}
```

if i write selector like this:

```
// assume that my redux state like above sample

const dataSelector = state => state.data;

export const sortedDataSelector = createSelector (
    dataSelector,
    data => {
        let sorted = [];

        // i sort data here
        data.map(dataX => {
            dataX.sort(_sort);
            sorted.push(dataX);
        })

        return sorted
    }
)

function _sort(a, b) {return a>b };
```

Then i use `sortedDataSelector` in my `mapStateToProps` like this:

```
const mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        soredData: sortedDataSelector(state);
    }
}
```

finally my app re-sort all dataX (`data1` or `data2`... or `dataN`) in `state.data` when one of dataXs change. in another word, `data1`, `data2`...`dataN` is resorted. Now i want my sortedDataSelector funtion re-sort only dataX when have any dataX change. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by using immutable library